# Assigning char array to pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to understand **pointers** in C++, but I am currently confused with the following:

```
char input_line[] = "hi?";
char* p;
p = &input_line;

while (*p)
{       
    cout << *p << endl;
    *p++;
}
```

I must be confused here because I would think this says assign the address of a **1d array** to the **pointer**; however, when I try to compile this, I get an error:  `error: cannot convert char (*)[4]' to 'char*' in assignment p = &input_line;`

It looks like I should be doing this:

```
const char input[] = "test?";
int quest_count = 0;
const char *i = input;

while(*i){
    cout << *i << endl;
    *i++;
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me because you are assigning a `char` **array** to a `char` **pointer** which stores an address.

Comment: `This doesn't make sense to me because you are assigning a char array to a char pointer` It makes sense because arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: `p = &input_line;` Tries to assign a "pointer to a `char` array", to a "pointer to `char`". Such types are incompatible. Did you mean to write `p = input_line;`?

Comment: In most cases array names are converted to pointers.

Comment: `p = input_line` will work

Comment: Use neither pointers nor arrays in C++. There is no reason to, as there are better alternatives nowadays.

Comment: Also, `*p++;` and `*i++;` should be `p++;` and `i++;` instead, since you are not using the values of `*p` and `*i` in those statements.  You could remove those statements and do the increment in the previous `cout` statements, though: `cout << *p++ << endl;` and `cout << *i++ << endl;`

Answer (score 7):

> The error in this line of code:
>
> ```
> p = &input_line;
> ```
>
> Can be resolved by changing it with:
>
> ```
> p = input_line;
> ```
>
> That's because your're assigning the memory direction of the **array**.
> Its value is a pointer to a char pointer. That's why the error is
> raised. Remember, the operator `&` gives to you the variables memory
> direction.

A **pointer** stores a memory direction of an object. An **array** is a sequence of objects by a certain type that are located in consecutives reserved amount of space in memory.

Each index of an **array** is a number composed of the digits from 0 to 9. Each element of an array is an object that you can take the address of, like a **pointer** to an object memory location. In an **array** the objects are located in consecutive memory locations. When you assign an **array** to a **pointer**, you're assigning the pointer to the **arrays** first element, it's `array[0]`.

When you increase by 1 the **pointer** value, the **pointer** will point to the next object in a memory location. So, **arrays and pointers** have similar behavior. If you assign to a **pointer** an **array** and then you increase by 1 the pointer value, it will point now to the object in the array.

[image: This image is taken from the page below mentioned.]

This is not only for `char` type, it's for every type in C++. [In this page](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/pointers-arrays)  you can get more information about pointers and array. **You must note that the pointer and the array must contain or point to the same variable type.**

> Here's an example from [this page](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/pointers-arrays):
>
> ```
> int* ptr;
> int a[5];
> ptr = &a[2];  // &a[2] is the address of third element of a[5].
> ```

An output example from the example in [this page](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/pointers-arrays) is:

> **Displaying address using arrays:**
>
> ```
> &arr[0] = 0x7fff5fbff880
> &arr[1] = 0x7fff5fbff884
> &arr[2] = 0x7fff5fbff888
> &arr[3] = 0x7fff5fbff88c
> &arr[4] = 0x7fff5fbff890
> ```
>
> **Displaying address using pointers:**
>
> ```
>  ptr + 0 = 0x7fff5fbff880
>  ptr + 1 = 0x7fff5fbff884
>  ptr + 2 = 0x7fff5fbff888
>  ptr + 3 = 0x7fff5fbff88c
>  ptr + 4 = 0x7fff5fbff890
> ```

As you can note in the output example, both are pointing to the same memory location, so you can access the objects from both methods.

Formally, in the [C++ 11 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.array) is mentioned that:

> Array-to-pointer conversion:
>
> ---
>
> An lvalue or rvalue of type “`array` of `N` `T`” or “`array` of
> unknown bound of `T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
> to `T`”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the `array`.

You can see those pages for more information about this theme:

[C++ Pointer to an Array.](http://www.c4learn.com/cplusplus/cpp-pointer-array/)

[C++ Pointers and Arrays.](https://codescracker.com/cpp/cpp-pointers-arrays.htm)

[C++ Pointer to an Array.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_to_an_array.htm)

[C++11 Standard Library Extensions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-library-stl#std-array)

Comment: Slight nitpick: an array is not a set in the mathematical sense of the word "set" which I only bring up because set theory is pretty important to computer science.  A set doesn't have any particular order (i.e. `std::set` does a little more than a set) and it doesn't have duplicates.  Arrays are often used to store what happen to be sets, but just as often repetition or the sequence matter e.g. in a string.  Use the word "sequence" instead of "set", I guess?

Comment: Ok! Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

From the [C++11 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.array) (emphasis mine):

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of `N T`” or “array of unknown bound of `T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`”. **The result is a pointer to the first element of the array**.

This conversion, conversion of an array to a pointer to the first element of the array, is commonly know as "an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array".

This conversion applies to all types, not just `char`.

```
int array_1[10] = {};
int* ptr1 = array_1;     // ptr1 is a pointer to the first element of array_1

double array_2[10] = {};
double* ptr2 = array_2;  // ptr2 is a pointer to the first element of array_2
```