# Assigning a pointer to an array in not working but the reverse is fine

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The value in a is copied to c pointer:

```
char a[] = "I am ok";
char *c = a;
```

Getting compilation error:

```
char *c = "I am ok";
char a[] = c;
```

Why?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Both statements in the second example should be giving you an error.

Comment: *"The value in a is copied to c pointer."* - is not.

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char []'
note: There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays

Comment: Not the values copied the pointer c will hold the address of a[0] element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning char array to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027421/assigning-char-array-to-pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array can only be initialized using [*aggregate initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (with a special-case for literals strings, as used in the first case).

The initialization-part in the second case is simply not correct according to the language.

Furthermore, literal strings (as is used in the initialization of `c` in the second case) are arrays of *constant* characters, meaning you can't make a non-constant pointer to a literal string. You must use `const char*`.

---

As for why it works in the first case, first of all the array `a` is not constant, so no need for a pointer to `const`. Secondly when using an array it can *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

So the definition:

```
char* c = a;
```

is really this:

```
char* c = &a[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

because the

```
char *c
```

is a declaration of the pointer and not its content it can only be initialized by an Adress