# Too many initializer values and write access violation

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory

I am trying to answer a daily coding problem. It make a finished dominoes pattern given one. For example if the input char array is "r,.,.,.,l,.,." your finished pattern should be "r,r,.,l,l,.,.".

Two problems. When, in main, I declare the char array as a pointer I get the error that I have to many initializers. I fixed this by declaring the input array as an array. But I want to use pointers. So this is unacceptable. Second problem. On line 11 in the Dominos function, list[i] = 'r'; produces a write acces violation error. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

char* Dominos(char* list, int size) {
    int i = 0, medianOffset = 0, count = 0, odd = 0, post = 0;
    if (list[i] == 'r') {
        while (list[i] != 'l') {
            list[i] = 'r';
            i++;
            count++;
            }
        medianOffset = (count - 1) / 2;
        odd = count % 2;
        post = i;
        if (odd == 1) {//putting lefts down when there is no dot seperating l and r
            for (int j = 0; j < medianOffset; j++) {
                list[i] = 'l';
                i--;
            }
        }
        else {//put a dot between l and r
            for (int j = 0; j < medianOffset; j++) {
                //list[i] = 'l';
                i--;
            }
            list[i] = '.';
        }
    }
    else if (list[i] == 'l') {

    }
    else {

    }
    return list;
}

int main() {

    char *c = { 'r', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'};
    int size = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << c[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    char* list = Dominos(c, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << *(list+i);
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem can be resolved by this [assigning-char-array-to-pointer _ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027421/assigning-char-array-to-pointer).

The second problem i think is due to the failure to check `i < size_of_the_array` in the while loop.

Comment: Okay that was the problem, it was a seg fault. I think. But ya it went into garbage array values.