# If an array_name is a pointer how isnt int *ptr = array_name not a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am a beginner in C and have recently came across the fact that an array name is a pointer to the address of the first element of an array, that is a pretty understandable concept since a pointer is a variable that holds a memory address.

```
int x[4];
printf("%p",x); // x is  a pointer
```

What i am having problems understanding is the following code:

```
int x[4], *ptr;
ptr = x;
```

This is simple enough but the second line `ptr = x`  points to the pointer `x`, would this not making `ptr` a pointer to a pointer meaning i would need to declare `ptr` as `int **ptr` ? If my understanding is not mistaken, `x`stores the address of `x[0]` so doing `ptr = x`, is making `ptr` point to another pointer which is `x` making it essentially pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning char array to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027421/assigning-char-array-to-pointer)

Comment: No, in `ptr = x;` x will *decay* to a **pointer-expression** (that is: a value with the **type** `pointer to int)

Comment: You might like section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin not really i am already familiar with the fact that &array_name refers to the whole array and array_name refers to the first element of the array

Comment: @wildplasser ok i understand it will decay but from what? decaying means the type changes, so before the decay takes place what is the type of array_name? and even if it does decay, i still see ```ptr = x``` as a pointer pointing to a pointer.

Comment: The array **name** decays to a pointer **expression** This is not very different from a scalar assignment: `int a,b; a=1;; b= a;` here `a` *"decays"* to a's **value**.

Comment: @pmg thanks that article is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is not a pointer.

But first, let’s look at the assignment. Suppose you have:

```
int SomeInt;
int *a = &SomeInt;
```

At this point `a` points to `SomeInt`. Then we do:

```
int *b;
b = a;
```

What does this do? It sets `b` equal to `a`. It does not make `b` point to `a`. After this assignment, `b` has the same value as `a`, so `b` points to the same place `a` points to; it points to `SomeInt`. It does not point to `a`.

Similarly, your `ptr = x;` does not make `ptr` point to `x`. It makes `ptr` equal to the value of the expression `x`.

However, in this case, that value is not the array, because there is an automatic conversion occurring. We will discuss that below.

Getting back to arrays not being pointers, after `int x[4];`, `x` is the name of the array of four `int`. If you print the size of the array, with `printf("%zu\n", sizeof x);`, you will get 16 on systems where `int` is four bytes, because the size of the array is 16 bytes. This is because `x` is the array, so `sizeof x` is the size of the array.

However, when you write `ptr = x;`, it does not assign the array to `ptr`. It assigns a pointer to the first element to `ptr`. How does that work?

Because early C did not have any support for working with whole arrays, such as assigning one to another, you had to work with them only through pointers. So, to set a pointer to point to the first element of an array, you would have to write `ptr = &x[0];`. To make this easier, the language was designed to allow you to write `ptr = x;` instead. When you use an array in this way, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, as if you had written `&array[0]` instead of `array`.

That automatic conversion occurs whenever an array is used in an expression except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.